# How to print out a text while 'save as' dialog is shown in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, outputstream

I am having a program which picks a pdf file and let user download it. I do use `OutputStream` for that and it works fine.

However, on the same page, I want to display a text (on an actual website, for the user).

I have tried the `PrintWriter` but that was in contrary with the `OutputStream`, throwing an error saying I can't use them at the same time.
So I decided to use `ServletOutputStream's` `print()` which didn't work. For some reason nothing was printed on the screen.

**CODE**:

```
File pdfFile = new File(filePath);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
            + "EloquaEmail.pdf");
    response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
    OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
    }
// SOMEWHERE HERE I WOULD LIKE TO PRINT OUT THE TEXT (Some variable)
// I've tried:
//      ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
//      PrintWriter responseOutputStream = response.getWriter();
//      responseOutputStream.print(Main.htmlCode);
//      responseOutputStream.close();
```

**EDIT**:
Or would it be possible to open a new JSP page (besides the one with the save as dialog), passing the text variable? You know to simulate `target=_blank` from within the servlet class?

I have tried this:

```
String message = Main.htmlCode;
request.setAttribute("message", message); // This will be available as ${message}
request.getRequestDispatcher("../WebContent/DownloadHtmlCode.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Throws this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
```

Comment: If you want to print something on the screen use: `System.out.println("...")`. Also you cannot send two types (`application/pdf` and `text/html`) down the same stream.

Comment: I want to print it out for the user, meaning on the servlet page... but thanks

Comment: I think, you need to invoke 2 requests/responses: first step is delivering a new page, displaying the message for the user. Upon loading you create a second request with javascript to trigger the .pdf download.

Comment: Would you mind answering my question? Because I think you are right. Maybe some sample code could help as well.

Comment: All of these code are in same servlet method?

Comment: Yes, I found out that it isn't a right way to do it because one request cant return 2 responses.

Answer (score 0):

You normally do that, by adding to your a jsp page which contains your text in  meta tag:

```
 String message = Main.htmlCode;
 response.setHeader("Refresh", "5;url=Display.jsp?message="+message);
```